# Where to instantiate an object used in several parts of a Django/Python application?

Tags: python, django

I realize this is a very basic question. Please see the disclaimers and context below if this just seems plain stupid!

I often have an object representing a resource -- for example a Redis queue -- that is used in several places in my Django application.  However, the resource is not necessarily invoked in every single HTTP request.

Should I:

1. Instantiate the object once, and import it into the
   relevant modules?
2. Or, instantiate the object locally in each module where it is needed?

### Option 1

*shared.py*

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
```

*views1.py*

```
from shared import queue
# ... use the queue
```

*views2.py*

```
from shared import queue
# ... use the queue
```

### Option 2

*views1.py*

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
# ... use the queue
```

*views2.py*

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
# ... use the queue
```

### Disclaimers & Context

I'm sure this question seems elementary. I realize both methods work -- I'm really asking so that I can gain a better understanding of the fundamentals involved.

What are the implications and consequences of these two approaches?  Are there advantages to using Option 1 in certain circumstances, and Option 2 in others?

I've read up a bit on python's import system and found those concepts somewhat confusing. I also don't entirely understand how the python process that runs a Django application works. Specifically, (1) when objects are being loaded, (2) whether every object is retained in memory during the lifetime of the python process, and (3) how and whether that python process persists through multiple HTTP requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If instantiation is costly in terms of time and resources or if you want to reuse the same object at different places, in that case you can use something like a singleton and import it in whichever view you need, otherwise you can instantiate the objected where and when you need it. In your case for reds, making an object again and again will incur overhead and you could benifit from using a connection pool. More on this here - http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is probably best. This is in effect making it a singleton, which is used wherever you need it.

In terms of your follow-up questions, everything at module level is executed when that module is first imported in a process. When subsequent modules import the first module, it is not executed again; they just get additional references to the same object. So in this case there would be a single instantiation of your queue. Objects remain in memory for as long as there are references to them; since this object is instantiated at module level and assigned to a module-level variable, the instance will persist in memory for the duration of the process.

There are quite a few questions here about how processes work in Django; suffice to say that although this depends to some extent on the server that is running it, almost all ways of running Django consist of multiple processes each of which persist for many requests. Again, in your case each server process would have its own single reference to the queue object.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.  I appreciate the additional background info.